# How to increase the width of the toggle switch

Tags: html, css

How can i increase the toggle switch size using simple CSS code and below you can

find the code in HTML & CSS.

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}
.switch input {display:none;}
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}
.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}
input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}
input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label>
```

When i increase the width in .switch class only the width increases but the toggle stays in the middle it when i toggle it I.E it doesn't move to the extreme end. I need how can i move the toggle switch to the extreme end.

Answer (score 2):

You could change the slider position using `left` instead of `translateX`, this will allow you to change the width of the switch without effecting the behavior of the slider

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 34px;
}
.switch input {display:none;}
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}
.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}
input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}
input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before { 
  /* 30px = 26px (slider's width) + 4px (for the margin) */
  left: calc(100% - 30px);
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to increase what you are passing to `transformX()` function calls in `input:checked + .slider:before` as well. You must add exactly the same number of pixels as what you want to add to the width

In the example below, I've increased the toggle switch size by 30px - see comments in the code below.

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90px; /* Added 30px here */
  height: 34px;
}
.switch input {display:none;}
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}
.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}
input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}
input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(56px); /* Added 30px here... */
  -ms-transform: translateX(56px); /* ... here... */
  transform: translateX(56px); /* ...and here too! ;) */
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the CSS applied when the checkbox is checked to move the slider to the right:

```
input:checked + .slider:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
    -o-transform: translateX(26px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(26px);
    transform: translateX(26px);
}
```

I added `-moz-` and `-o-` prefixes for Mozilla and Opera.

You need to change that to your specification after increasing the width.

Here is a fiddle with bigger width and the slider to the right:
http://jsfiddle.net/v8gz2xr5/3/

The HTML(As it is):

```
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label>
```

The CSS:

```
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px; /* width increased */
  height: 34px;
}
.switch input {display:none;}
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}
.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}
input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}
input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(160px); /* Move the slider to the right */
  -ms-transform: translateX(160px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(160px);
  -o-transform: translateX(160px);
  transform: translateX(160px);
}
```